# Why is 011 + 001 giving me 011?

Tags: binary

I'm building a mini binary calculator, and using this logic I am able to combine 2 digit binary numbers (0-3, in decimal) to return at most a 3 digit binary number (0-6, 7 is unreachable with what I have):

[image]

However, there's trouble when I combine 3 and 1: it returns 2 and not 4, whereas combining 2 and 2 returns 4. I'm new to binary/logic gates, and I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening, and if there is another way to arrange the gates to allow an output of 4 when combining 3 and 1?

Comment: Post your code, not an offsite link.

Comment: My "code" is a diagram, an image.

Comment: Same applies - not many people are going to go offsite to help you.

Comment: Try solving a simpler problem first. Make a set of gates where you can enter 3 and 1, and the output is 4, and then try to combine that with what you have. Then simplify the things that are in common.

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to post the image, only the link. Thanks for the edit, guys :)

And I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seam to have misunderstood the purpose of `Cin (carry in)` and `Cout (carry out)`. In all its simpleness, carry represents an overflow. Which is used to overflow into the next digit of the addition.

## 1-bit Half Adder

You already got the half adder right. It's just an `XOR` for the `sum` and an `AND` for the `Cout (carry out)`.

[image: 1-bit Half Adder]

## 1-bit Full Adder

Making a full adder, is just 2 half adders. That receives the A, B bits and the `Cin` from the last **full** adder in the chain of full adders for the addition.

[image: 1-bit Full Adder]

## 4-bit Full Adder

However many bits you need to add together, you can always use the last and "unused" `Cout` to detect whether the result overflows or not.

[image: 4-bit Full Adder]